# Why I am getting an anamolous behaviour while printing elements of an array

Tags: c

I am getting an unexpected result while running the code. As I expected that this code prints array elements as it is. But I am getting different output for first 4 elements. Why it is so?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ int i,a[8]={000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111};
  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
  printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting and what did you get?

Comment: Oh the "unexpected" result comes from the fact that a 0 starting number in C is assumed to be in base 8

Comment: In C, `main` must return type `int`, not `void`, though that's probably not the underlying cause of your issue..

Comment: @Aakanksha Can you explain what is the different result for outputting the value 000?:)

Comment: If you want at least three digits in the output, say so: `printf("%.3d\n", a[i]);`.  But you still have an octal vs decimal issue — the compiler does what you told it to do, but you didn't mean to tell it to do what you told it to do.

Answer (score 3):

[Integer constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) that begin with the digit 0 are **octal** (base 8). The literals 010 and 011 are the values 8 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

Specify *octal* output with `"%o"` (not `"%d"`)

```
printf("%o %03o\n", 9, 9); // 11 011
```

See [ideone.com/Yy5yNA](https://ideone.com/Yy5yNA)